# How to set date format for nginx $date_local

Tags: nginx, configuration, config

According to [the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#var_date_local) you can set the date format in nginx with the command `config timefmt` but I can't find any documentation/example on where or how to set that.

The default shows a string like "Sunday, 26-Oct-2014 21:05:24 Pacific Daylight Time" and I want to change it to `yyyyMMdd`

I'm running nginx on Windows if that makes a difference.

Thank you

Comment: Ah.. this has been asked **JUST** today, and I need the same question answered..!!

Comment: Check this out, it might help: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSetMiscModule

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must not have read the [ngx_http_ssi_module documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html) properly (especially its ['SSI Commands' section](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#commands)): it explains the commands format.

You need to set the [`ssi`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#ssi) directive to `on` in the context you wish SSI commands to be parsed, then you need to serve files there which contains those commands.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    index index.txt;

    location / {
        ssi on;
    }
}
```

The [`$date_local`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#var_date_local) variable states that it must be configured with the `config` command, by settings its `timefmt` parameter.

You just need to serve files which will send commands back, such as `index.txt`:

```
<!--# config timefmt="%A, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z" -->
```

The format being used by the `timefmt` parameter is the one of the [`strftime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) standard C function (as the documentation states).

Comment: i guess for php, it will be /*# config timefmt="%A, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z" */, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: SSI parse *responses* and interpret (textual) commands there. There is no notion of backend, thus no PHP...