# HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified String added in end of the file

Tags: javascript, nginx, networking, http-status-code-304

I am using NGINX load balancer.
When we load our web page, one of the javascript resources giving "HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified" string at end of the file.

I checked the resources(js file) in the server and it doesn't have "HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified" string at the end. But on browser sometime I am seeing this string in end of the file response.

Because of that this js file is not loading.

Comment: We need to know more about your setup. What web platform are you using, and please give a example of the code causing the trouble.

Comment: I added a folder in my nginx load balancer and make it accessible through server url. I pasted a javascript file in that folder and gave the link to my client. That links working good for me.  Client added that link in their html import and they faced some latency. While investigating in browser js response it seems  "HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified" string appended in end of the file and I see the same error in console too. But in the server the file is good. Weird thing is It is not happening all the time

Comment: I would try turning off caching on your nginx server to try to debug it. I wonder if the client javascript is appending the response to the js file when nginx responds with the fact that the server side resource has not changed relative to the browser cache.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243633/disable-nginx-cache-for-javascript-files try that to see if you can get it to resolve, then see if you can debug the issue from there.