# How to insert Unix timestamp by using Nginx SSI (server side includes)?

Tags: nginx, web, server, ssi

I was reading the instructions, yet there is no example for me to understand how to insert a timestamp. I require Unix timestamp or any type of a date that I can format myself.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#commands

The final goal is to have timestamp inserted in a manner how I like it, to prevent the contact form abuse. And in case that spammers adopt to it, I would change the format.

Comment: Check this answer about SSI timefmt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26780792/644386

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>                                                                                                                                  
  <body>                                                                                                                                
    Time <!--# config timefmt="%F" --><!--# echo var="date_local" -->                                                                   
  </body>                                                                                                                               
</html>
```

Thank you Aleksey. I will use the above solution, while changing the formatting if spammers adopt to it. But I guess their software is not easily adoptable.